# Unable to log into samba server

Tags: windows-7, samba, network-share, log-files, fedora

I am unable to log into a samba server (running on fedora core 6) as it prompts for a username and password when I try to connect to the mapped drives from my windows 7 machine.

I decided to reset the password using the command `smbpassword paddy` and when I list users using check the `pdbedit -L -v`  I see that the password was updated at the time I made this change.

However, I am still unable to log in. The log file in `/var/log/samba/log.paddy` shows:

```
[2012/10/11 09:55:54.605923,  1] smbd/service.c:678(make_connection_snum)
  create_connection_server_info failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
[2012/10/11 09:55:54.606635,  1] smbd/service.c:678(make_connection_snum)
  create_connection_server_info failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

How can I resolve this so that I can log in?

Comment: Did this work before or failed on your first connection attempt? Did older XP clients connect without problems?

Comment: It worked before. I can see the different folders on the server but cannot log in to access the data. The issue that only can is the IP of the server was changed to something else and I then reset it back to the initial IP address it has always been.